# proof of substition of integrals by chain rule

Tags: integration, substitution, chain-rule

I am trying to prove substitution of integrals by going from the chain rule. Here is my attempt:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(u)=\frac{d}{du}f\frac{d}{dx}u$$

$$\int \frac{d}{dx}f(u)dx=\int \frac{d}{du}f \frac{d}{dx}u dx=\int \frac{df}{du} du $$

In other words what we need is the core $\frac{du}{dx}dx=du$

So by taking $\frac{du}{dx}dx$ out and replacing it with du we have arrived at a new integral:

$$\int \frac{df}{du} du $$

Is this correct? It seems that we are using the chain rule to arrive at this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the regularity of your functions. Lets say that $f$ is continuous on some interval $I=]a,b[$ and that $g$ is continuously differentiable on $J=]c,d[$ with values in $I$.

Now since $f$ is continuous it has an antiderivative $F$ such that $F'(u)=f(u)$ for all $u \in I$. Now lets define a function $h\colon J \to \mathbb R$ by $h(x) = F(g(x))$. Using the chain rule we get that:
\begin{equation}
 h'(x) = F'(g(x))g'(x) = f(g(x))g'(x).
\end{equation}
Thus $h$ is an antiderivative for $f(g(x))g'(x)$. Using the notation of indefinite integrals we have that:
\begin{equation}
 \int f(g(x))g'(x)dx = F(g(x)) = \int f(u) du_{|u=g(x)}.
\end{equation}

So in essence your argument is on the right track.